# Como saber quais servidores estão esperando conexão em minha rede?

Tags: java, socket

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo multiplayer (LAN) com Sockets em JAVA. Os jogadores irão iniciar um lobby, e nesse lobby haverá uma lista de servidores (salas de jogo) esperando por conexões.

Como posso listar os servidores que estão na minha rede para que os jogadores possam conectar-se?

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, João

A forma de fazer isso poderia ser tentando conexões com os servidores da sua faixa de IP na porta escolhida. Não recomendo que adote essa ideia, pois você precisaria conhecer os IP's da máquina (uma máquina pode responder a vários IP's), a faixa dentro da máscara de rede que eles usam e iterar sobre uma quantidade enorme de IP's para obter essa lista. Você tentaria a conexão e, se houver um "Connection Refused" significa que a outra máquina não está esperando receber nada naquela porta.

Uma forma mais interessante seria que um dos servidores centralizasse a lista com os IP/hostnames dos outros servidores de jogo. Sempre que um servidor de jogo iniciasse ele enviaria uma mensagem ao servidor centralizador informando seu IP atual.

Todos os lobbys então sempre perguntariam a esse servidor centralizador quais servidores de jogo existe e estão ativos, obteria o IP e então faria a conexão para o jogo.

Com essa técnica você as requisições de uma forma colossal e estabelece um processo simples para determinar a que IP conectar.

Comment: É uma boa solução, porém para este projeto não é viável o uso de um servidor central. Eu fiz o que essa [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3345981) sugeriu. Funciona, mas não consigo conectar a uma porta específica.

Comment: Esse exemplo só mostra como testar a capacidade de alcançar o host. A resposta do JLuann tem um exemplo de socket em uma porta específica.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver meu problema fazendo algumas edições num [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345981) que usei como base.

Código:

```
public void checkHosts(String subnet) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
        String host = subnet + "." + i;

        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, 3128);
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        boolean connected = false;

        try {
            socket.connect(sockaddr, timeout);
            connected = true;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            System.out.println(host + " isn't reachable");
        } catch (ConnectException ex) {
            System.out.println(host + " is reachable, but hasn't server on port 3128");
        }

        if (connected) {
            System.out.println(host + " has a server on port 3128!!!");
        }

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar listar o IP dos servidores nesse lobby. Para pegar o IP de um servidor você pode usar a seguinte função:

```
public String getIp() {

  InetAddress ip;

  try {

    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

    return ip.getHostAddress();

  } catch(UnknownHostException ex) {}

  return "IP não encontrado!";

}
```

Tente passar essa string do servidor para o lobby toda vez que um servidor novo for criado. E, quando for fechado, você tem que lembrar de tirar o IP do lobby também.

Espero ter ajudado!